# How to revoke access token of google drive login using google oauth2?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-api, google-oauth, access-token

I have google drive sign in feature in my react nodejs application. When ever a user clicks on sign in, I am using Google oauth2 to get code and that to get access token and refresh token using client ID and secret. I am saving these tokens and expiry in my database. Now, I want to revoke the token on logout. Below is the call I am making :

```
// token => storing refreshtoken
axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/revoke?token=${token}`, {
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("response = ", response)
      log('INFO', 'Inside getNewToken done')
      return response
    }).catch((error) => {
      log('ERROR','Inside getNewToken, Error : ', error)
      return error
    })
```

It's showing "Request failed with status code 404".
I also tried

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token=${token}
```

This is showing "Request failed with status code 400"
Where am I going wrong? The api to call is correct right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check googles discovery document [openid-configuration](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)

You will find that the revoke endpoint should be

> "revocation_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke",

You are using

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/revoke

Full disco doc responses

```
{
 "issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "authorization_endpoint": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
 "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/device/code",
 "token_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
 "userinfo_endpoint": "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo",
 "revocation_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke",
 "jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs",
 "response_types_supported": [
  "code",
  "token",
  "id_token",
  "code token",
  "code id_token",
  "token id_token",
  "code token id_token",
  "none"
 ],
 "subject_types_supported": [
  "public"
 ],
 "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
  "RS256"
 ],
 "scopes_supported": [
  "openid",
  "email",
  "profile"
 ],
 "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
  "client_secret_post",
  "client_secret_basic"
 ],
 "claims_supported": [
  "aud",
  "email",
  "email_verified",
  "exp",
  "family_name",
  "given_name",
  "iat",
  "iss",
  "locale",
  "name",
  "picture",
  "sub"
 ],
 "code_challenge_methods_supported": [
  "plain",
  "S256"
 ],
 "grant_types_supported": [
  "authorization_code",
  "refresh_token",
  "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
  "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
 ]
}
```

Remember that you can only revoke a token once so if it is revoked its going to give you an error if you try to revoke it again as it does not exist.

Comment: I tried the mentioned link also https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke but is there a problem with the way the token is sent?

Comment: if I recall its a get not a post.   you are sending the access token right

Comment: It's a post call. I am following the code provided in this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#node.js_8 I want convert the http call to axios call. Don't know where I am making a mistake

Comment: Well 400 error implies that the server doesn't understand what you are sending https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke

Comment: Sorry, it was mistake from my side. The 400 error was coming because I was calling the revoked token again for revoking. A mistake I had not realized until I tried google oauth playground. It's working fine now. Thank you for taking time to reply.

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it helped you this will also improve your own reputation.

Comment: Ah alright. Will do that from now on. Still getting used to stackoverflow. Thanks for telling